# Increment variable using react and map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React to count a certain attribute and its frequency within an object. I use a map() but the return function always shows the default value 0.

```
let countRechnung = 0;

React.useEffect(() => {
{
  dokumente.length &&
    dokumente.map((doc, key) => {
      if (doc.einordnung == 1) {
        countRechnung++;
      } else if (doc.einordnung == 2) {
        countWerbung++;
      } else if (doc.einordnung == 3) {
        countInfo++;
      } else {
        countSonstiges++;
      }
    });
 }
}, [dokumente]);


[...]

return(
  ...
 <MenuItem value={1}>Rechnungen ({countRechnung}) // It's 0 </MenuItem>
 ...)
```

Comment: remove useEffect

Answer (score 1):

To get this algorithm working you'll need to actually store the counted values. I'd recommend making use of `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`.

Try this:

```
const { countRechnung, countWerbung, countInfo, countSonstiges } = useMemo(() => {
  const results = {
    countRechnung: 0,
    countWerbung: 0,
    countInfo: 0,
    countSonstiges: 0,
  }
  dokumente.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.einordnung === 1) 
      results.countRechnung = results.countRechnung + 1;
    else if (doc.einordnung === 2) 
      results.countWerbung = results.countWerbung + 1;
    else if (doc.einordnung === 3) 
      results.countInfo = results.countInfo + 1;
    else
      results.countSonstiges= results.countSonstiges+ 1;
  });
  return results;
}, [dokumente])
```

Then in your implementation:

```
return (
  ...
  <MenuItem value={1}>Rechnungen ({countRechnung})</MenuItem>
  ...
)
```

No need to use `map` since you don't need to transform anything, rather just use `forEach`. Also no need to check for `dokumente` length.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs the code *after* rendering is complete. If you want to calculate something that effects the render result, you need to do it in the body of the component. Additionally, `.map`'s purpose is to create a new array. Since you're not using that array, you should probably use `.forEach` instead:

```
let countRechnung = 0;
dokumente.length &&
  dokumente.forEach((doc, key) => {
    if (doc.einordnung == 1) {
      countRechnung++;
    } else if (doc.einordnung == 2) {
      countWerbung++;
    } else if (doc.einordnung == 3) {
      countInfo++;
    } else {
      countSonstiges++;
    }
  });

[...]

return(
  ...
 <MenuItem value={1}>Rechnungen ({countRechnung}) // It's 0 </MenuItem>
 ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`countRechnung`  is redeclared `0` each render cycle and the `useEffect` hook runs *at the end* of the render cycle, so the UI will never see the mutated `countRechnung` value.

Use an array reduce to compute the `countRechnung` value. The array methods can handle empty arrays, so the array length check is a little unnecessary.

```
const counts = dokumente.reduce((counts, doc) => {
  if (doc.einordnung == 1) {
    counts.countRechnung++;
  } else if (doc.einordnung == 2) {
    counts.countWerbung++;
  } else if (doc.einordnung == 3) {
    counts.countInfo++;
  } else {
    counts.countSonstiges++;
  }
  return counts;
}, {
  countRechnung: 0,
  countWerbung: 0,
  countInfo: 0,
  countSonstiges: 0,
});

...

return(
  ...
    <MenuItem value={1}>
      Rechnungen ({counts.countRechnung})
    </MenuItem>
  ...
);
```

I think a `switch` state is a little more clean, but this is just my opinion.

```
const counts = dokumente.reduce((counts, doc) => {
  switch(Number(doc.einordnung)) {
    case 1:
      counts.countRechnung++;
      break;
    case 2:
      counts.countWerbung++;
      break;
    case 3:
      counts.countInfo++;
      break;
    default:
      counts.countSonstiges++;
  }
  return counts;
}, {
  countRechnung: 0,
  countWerbung: 0,
  countInfo: 0,
  countSonstiges: 0,
});
```

If this counting logic is expensive, memoize the result with the `useMemo` hook.

```
const counts = useMemo(() => {
  return dokumente.reduce((counts, doc) => {
    switch(Number(doc.einordnung)) {
      case 1:
        counts.countRechnung++;
        break;
      case 2:
        counts.countWerbung++;
        break;
      case 3:
        counts.countInfo++;
        break;
      default:
        counts.countSonstiges++;
    }
    return counts;
  }, {
    countRechnung: 0,
    countWerbung: 0,
    countInfo: 0,
    countSonstiges: 0,
  });
}, [dokumente]); // <-- recompute when `dokumente` value updates
```

Answer (score 0):

With every rerender the variable countRechnung is gonna get reset again. Place it outside the component or (better way) use the useState hook:

```
// Not sure if this one works: const [countRechnung, setCountRechnung] = React.useState(0);
const [countRechnung, incrementCountRechnung] = React.useReducer((s) => s + 1, 0) // s is the value it had before, calling incrementCountWerbung will increase the value by one, if you don't know what the useReducer is look it up
// You should also have a look at the React useState hook. Most of your variables will be set with useState in React

React.useEffect(() => {
{
  dokumente.length &&
    dokumente.map((doc, key) => {
      if (doc.einordnung == 1) {
        // if you use the commented out method: (Not sure if it works): setCountWerbung(countWerbung + 1)
        incrementCountRechnung()
      } else if (doc.einordnung == 2) {
        incrementCountWerbung()
      } else if (doc.einordnung == 3) {
        incrementCountInfo()
      } else {
        incrementSonstiges()
      }
    });
 }
}, [dokumente]);


[...]

return(
  ...
 <MenuItem value={1}>Rechnungen ({countRechnung}) // It's 0 </MenuItem>
 ...)
```